# Do I need to take L-glutamine if the whey protein contains it?

Tags: nutrition, supplements

I started off just taking L-glutamine before and after my workout and creatine after my workout.  I just started taking whey protein and noticed it contains L-glutamine.  Should I continue to take the L-glutamine with the Whey that also contains L-glutamine?

Comment: Also, creatine timing is somewhat important but I would put it low on your stress list. Maintaining your loaded levels day after day is going to have the biggest impact. http://jissn.biomedcentral.com/articles/10.1186/1550-2783-10-36 ..... note the "possibly more beneficial" line.

Comment: I'd also take note of where on your protein container shows it contains glutamine. If it appears on a separate panel with the other aminos, you should be fine. But if it shows up in the actual ingredients list, then you should find a new protein powder as it's spiked.

@EricKaufman: I wouldn't call it important at all, at least not for someone like OP. Most people see no benefit from nutrient timing to begin with.

Comment: @EricKaufman the whole creatine timing theory has been shot over and over. Just take it once a day at a specific time(morning, evening, doesnt matter) and youre okay.

Answer (score 1):

[Glutamine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glutamine) falls into the lower-tier category of supplements, where it would be extremely difficult for anyone to prove that it's going to make measurable impacts to performance. [Glutamine has positive impacts related to DOMS, as an example, but the impact is minor](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/16011/7091).

Glutamine is an amino acid found in a variety of dietary sources (most meats, eggs, beans, wheat, etc), and as you noted it's also found in whey.

Additionally, it's a **non-essential** amino acid, meaning your body can generally synthesize whatever it needs from other components. Occasionally your body would be unable to cover its glutamine needs from synthesis, but again you (most likely) get it in your diet already from a variety of sources.

So when you hear people talking about the benefits of glutamine, take all that into account. Anyone who swears up and down about the benefits of glutamine would need to prove that they require the supplementation of it, as they aren't naturally providing enough.

That's mighty hard to prove, anecdotal otherwise, and shows the overall marketing hype related to glutamine.